# 24h disconnect of ISP pauses download forever

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, disconnect

My ISP forces a disconnect on my connection once a day. If that occurs during a download, the download just pauses forvever, without throwing an exception whatsoever.

Right now I could only think of threading the download, then checking for a maximum time or reading the filesize evey now and then to check if it's still growing.

The functions I'm using right now:

```
def download_with_progress(url,localFileName,overwrite=False):
    if not os.path.exists(localFileName) or overwrite == True:
        urlretrieve(url, localFileName, reporthook=print_progress)
        sys.stdout.write("\r") #remove previously printed percent sign
        sys.stdout.flush()

def print_progress(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    total_MB = (totalSize) / (1000 * 1000)
    current_MB = (blockSize * count) / (1000 * 1000)
    percent = int(count*blockSize*100/totalSize)        
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d%% (%d/%d MB)" % (percent, current_MB, total_MB))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Since I'm already here: is `total_MB`or `current_MB` correctly calculated that way? Or should I divide by `1024 * 1024` ? I'm displaying them as rounded int, so it's not really a problem.

Comment: The title of your post has nothing to do with the question you are asking. What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: My download function works fine, but if the connection to the internet is lost (for like 5 seconds) the download is forever frozen. It doesn't throw an exception whatsoever but simply freezes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `urllib2`, use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/); it sets the [TCP Keep-Alive option](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive) letting you detect ISP disconnects.

You may need to set additional socket options; the `urllib3` library uses `select` to detect if sockets are still available, and sets timeouts, but adding an explicit KEEPALIVE option to the socket should make detection a little smoother still:

```
import httplib
import socket

orig_connect = httplib.HTTPConnection.connect
def new_connect(self):
    orig_connect(self)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
httplib.HTTPConnection.connect = new_connect
```

Comment: looks nice, will check it out

Comment: Can you tell me how to install/copy requests that way, that I can ship it with my programm in one folder?

Comment: If it is sitting in the same folder as your script, you should be able to use it directly. You can also add a separate `packages` subdir and add that directory to `sys.path`. `requests` uses a `packages` sub-package and imports from `requests.packages.<subpackagename>` for dependencies.